# How should you allocate azure functions to receive different callouts or webhooks?

Tags: .net, azure, azure-functions

Our application listens for about 5 callouts from a single third-party provider.  The JSON payloads from each are almost identical, and vary only slightly.

Our application architecture sends the callouts to azure functions that send a message to a service bus, which then calls another azure function to send it to our web application.

Should I write a different azure function to consume each type of callout?  Or should I write one azure function that handles all 5 different callout messages, and then triage the callout-type in my web-application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use one function, you can input the callout as the param of the request, and then do different logic about different callout.

Just like this:

In your app get the callout as the param of the request to hit the function:

`http://localhost:7071/api/Function1?callout=111`

Then in your function process it:

```
[FunctionName("Function1")]
public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
    ILogger log)
{
    string callout = req.Query["callout"];
    if (callout == "xxx") {
        //some logic
    }
    else (callout == "yyy"){ 
        //some logic
    }
    //...
    return new OkObjectResult("xxx");
}
```